# Issue with IE conditional comments and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, google-analytics

I have a web-page that starts like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>      
<head>      
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <script>
        location.href = "http://www.getfirefox.com";
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

That page gets ~500 pageviews/month and for the last 6 months I had no IE visitors according to Google Analytics. However, a few days ago I got a report of an IE6 visit. How did that happen?

Did the redirection code in the conditional comment fire to late?
Did Google Analytics code mistakingly identified a non-IE browser as IE6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You register no IE visits because your script with `location.href = ...` runs before the Google Analytics code gets a chance to run.

You could have registered that IE6 visit if

1. IE 6 failed to do the location.href assignment (I've seen problems reported with this) but did run the analytics js code.
2. <strike>An IE 6 visitor had javascript turned off</strike>
   (in this case they wouldn't run the analytics code either, so wouldn't register a visit)
3. Another browser is impersonating IE 6, e.g. in the User-Agent string, but doesn't process the conditional comments.

You can move your conditional comment and the script within it to the end of the page, after the analytics js code if you want Google to count it but still send them off to getfirefox.com

You can also just say

```
<!--[if IE]
...
```

don't test a specific version if you always want to send IE away.

Comment: Wait, useragent string? Does Google Analytics identify browsers based on that?

Comment: @Šime - probably not since it's Google and They Know Better, but a lot of people still (mistakenly) try to use it.

Comment: @Stephne Yea, I would say so too. It's over 1500 lines of code, they must have a fairly strong browser detection technique inside. Which would mean that IE6 most likely failed to execute the redirection.

Comment: Google certainly does use the user agent string for IDing browsers. Look at the request headers for a __utm.gif request; user agent is the only browser info sent. Spoofing is not widespread enough to be an issue. Check out Safari spoofing as IE6: http://d.pr/HYSq; GA thinks I'm IE 6, but I won't execute the IE-only conditionals. #3 is the likeliest answer.

Comment: @Stephen its only a mistake to rely on it for individual users as gospel. For aggregated web analytics data, its imperfections can be ignored.

Comment: @yc - I'll definitely agree with that; the "mistake" I mean is trying to decide what javascript calls/features to use based on the user agent string, instead of testing the features directly in the js.

Answer (score 1):

He had javascript disabled.

Also, nice usability. You know they're not going to download firefox and then come back, right?

Comment: But then Google Analytics wouldn't work either - it's a script.

Comment: Yea, I know. It's not a commercial site. They don't have to come back, I couldn't care less.